# how do I pass a value to the setTextFormat?

Tags: actionscript-3

my array looks like this:
var cont1:Array = new Array("300","30", "1, 0xFF0000, 1", "0xFFFFFF,1","yes", "myFormat","200","200", "the text", "10","5", "yes");

TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "myFormat" to flash.text.TextFormat.
    at myclass_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

im getting that? what is the proper way of passing the myFormat to the setTextFormat.

Comment: Why would you imagine the string "myFormat" should convert to type `flash.text.TextFormat`?

Comment: oh sorry I tried without quotes and it wasnt working, it must have been because the format was set afterwards

Comment: You should try the docs http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/

Comment: you should try http://www.thedailywtf.com better :xd: ..!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have Array's and class contructors mixed up.

you can't do this:

```
var cont1:Array = new Array("300","30", "1, 0xFF0000, 1", "0xFFFFFF,1","yes", "myFormat","200","200", "the text", "10","5", "yes");
var textFormat : TextFormat = new TextFormat( cont1 ); //this will throw an error;
```

generally you would construct a TextFormat using it's class methods like this:

```
var textFormat : TextFormat = new TextFormat();
textFormat.font = "Verdana"
textFormat.color = 0xFF0000;
textFormat.size = 10;
textFormat.underline = true;
```

then apply it to your textfield

```
label.defaultTextFormat = textFormat;
```